# iOS App rejected non public api (SSL related) on cocos2d-x and libCurl

Tags: c++, ios, ssl, libcurl, cocos2d-x

I just submitted for review and app built on top of cocos2d-x (C++) and libcurl.

I m using libcurl with SSL support in order to download profile pictures from Facebook

When I validate my app from organiser or trying to distribute I get the following error:

Your app contains non public API usage . please reviex the errors..

The app references non-public symbols in Payload/....app/ {appName}:SSLCopyPeerCertificates,  {appName}:SSLDisposeContext etc..

When I search for this functions in the app I get no matches, but I think it s related to libcurl as  I dont use SSL expect in code related to libcurl

Any  suggestions ?

I sent a message to appreview at apple but I m afraid this might be long.

screenshot of the error : http://accessdev.s3.amazonaws.com/apps/ssl_reject.png

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you checked the box that you app uses cryptography?

Comment: Oh, forget my previous comment. Looks like curl uses OpenSSL .dylib. Try to build OpenSSL/curl as static libraries.

Comment: I checked the included libcurl.a in the problem and view hex view I can see usage of SSLDisposeContext & co , so this is confirmed that curl is the real source of the problem

Comment: You can check it also with ld , it will show what it imports and from which dylibs

Comment: You may want to use a recent version of libcurl (if it is not the case). As of 7.27.0 libcurl ships with native SSL support on-top of Mac OS X and iOS APIs. Please refer to this [blog post](http://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2012/06/28/darwin-native-ssl-for-curl/) and Nick Zitzmann's [pre-built libcurl](http://seiryu.home.comcast.net/~seiryu/libcurl-ios.html): "_As far as I know, neither binary includes any actual cryptography or digest-generating code. It uses the Security framework and CommonCrypto library for all of its cryptography and digest-generation needs._". This may help vs app review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suggest is to use the latest libcurl release, i.e. 7.28.1 version at the time of writing. This includes several fixes related to iOS native SSL APIs, see:

- http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2012-10/0142.html
- https://github.com/bagder/curl/commit/f1d2e1850819f54d1c950989614da7445bdd457f

I assume this should solve your issues vs the various symbols your are not supposed to use (`SSLDisposeContext`, etc).

If I refer to Nick's [libcurl 7.28.1 iOS build](http://seiryu.home.comcast.net/~seiryu/libcurl-ios.html) the non-public symbols that are listed within the Xcode warning window you've attached can't be found:

```
$ xcrun -sdk iphoneos nm -j -arch armv7 libcurl-device.a 2>/dev/null | grep SSL
_SSLClose
_SSLCopyPeerTrust
_SSLCreateContext
_SSLGetBufferedReadSize
_SSLGetNegotiatedCipher
_SSLGetNegotiatedProtocolVersion
_SSLGetSessionState
_SSLHandshake
_SSLRead
_SSLSetConnection
_SSLSetIOFuncs
_SSLSetPeerDomainName
_SSLSetProtocolVersionMax
_SSLSetProtocolVersionMin
_SSLSetSessionOption
_SSLWrite
```

Of course the same applies with the `armv7s` architecture.

Comment: thanks , I will try this tomorrow and let you know. according to the output you posted, it should be ok !

Comment: the problem has been fixed after updating libCURL

Comment: BTW: if you use it to perform file upload (over HTTPS) keep in mind that there is a bug recently found in 7.28.1: see this [thread](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2013-01/0295.html) - at the time of writing a patch has already been submitted.