# libcurl linker error on Xcode5 but working fine on Xcode 4.6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, llvm, libcurl

I have a project which uses **libcurl.all.a**. It builds, links and runs perfectly on Xcode 4.6.3. But in Xcode5, it throws linker errors on undefined symbols. The error log is as follows.

```
  Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_SSLCopyPeerCertificates", referenced from:
      _darwinssl_connect_common in libcurl.all.a(libcurl_la-curl_darwinssl.o)
  "_SSLDisposeContext", referenced from:
      _Curl_darwinssl_close in libcurl.all.a(libcurl_la-curl_darwinssl.o)
      _Curl_darwinssl_shutdown in libcurl.all.a(libcurl_la-curl_darwinssl.o)
      _darwinssl_connect_common in libcurl.all.a(libcurl_la-curl_darwinssl.o)
  "_SSLNewContext", referenced from:
      _darwinssl_connect_common in libcurl.all.a(libcurl_la-curl_darwinssl.o)
  "_SSLSetEnableCertVerify", referenced from:
      _darwinssl_connect_common in libcurl.all.a(libcurl_la-curl_darwinssl.o)
  "_SSLSetProtocolVersionEnabled", referenced from:
      _darwinssl_connect_common in libcurl.all.a(libcurl_la-curl_darwinssl.o)
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

SecurityFramework is already there in the project, and i have set **Build Active Architecture Only** to No. And since it compiles in Xcode 4.6.3, I don't think it got anything to do with missing target membership.

Is there any way to resolve this? Or a possible workaround, Its very essential to have this library working with Xcode5, since it needs to be used in an iOS7 application.

Comment: would you check what `lipo -info libcurl.all.a` returns? is the i386 family in there?

Comment: @sergio: Yup, its there `Architectures in the fat file: libcurl.all.a are: i386 armv7 (cputype (12) cpusubtype (11))`. Xcode5 builds for standard architecture armv7 and armv7s, can that be a problem?

Comment: What is the version of libcurl you are working with? You should take care to use a *recent* enough version (i.e 7.28.1+) since important fixes related to DarwinSSL have been introduced (such as use of APIs that only exist on OS X). See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13776322/ios-app-rejected-non-public-api-ssl-related-on-cocos2d-x-and-libcurl/13779449#13779449) for more details. This could explain your link errors (these symobls do not exist in DarwinSSL).

Comment: @deltheil: Perfect!, yup my version of libcurl was old, changed and recompiled it. Got it working. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, am posting the answer so that it could be useful for anyone who might face a similar situation. I was able to sort out the issue from the comments of @deltheli and @sergio, so many thanks to them for helping out.

So, I had to run 
    [lipo](http://mac.commands.com/lipo/) -info 
to know the supported architectures, and 
found that armv7s and arm64 was not supported, so i tried compiling it in armv7, which failed and explains the problem why it works perfectly in Xcode 4.6 and not in 5. My libcurl was outdated! And the version I used didn't support some of the `DarwinSSL` symbols. Using a recent enough version fixed the issue for me.