# issues while staticaly linking libcurl in xcode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, libcurl

I'm getting the following linker errors

> `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_SSLDisposeContext", referenced from:
>         _darwinssl_connect_common in libcurl.a(libcurl_la-curl_darwinssl.o)
>         _Curl_darwinssl_close in libcurl.a(libcurl_la-curl_darwinssl.o)
>     "_SSLNewContext", referenced from:
>         _darwinssl_connect_common in libcurl.a(libcurl_la-curl_darwinssl.o)
>     "_SSLSetEnableCertVerify", referenced from:
>         _darwinssl_connect_common in libcurl.a(libcurl_la-curl_darwinssl.o)
>     "_SSLSetProtocolVersionEnabled", referenced from:
>         _darwinssl_connect_common in libcurl.a(libcurl_la-curl_darwinssl.o)
>     "_SecCertificateCopyLongDescription", referenced from:
>         _darwinssl_connect_common in libcurl.a(libcurl_la-curl_darwinssl.o)
>         _append_cert_to_array in libcurl.a(libcurl_la-curl_darwinssl.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

lipo -info says: `Architectures in the fat file: libcurl.a are: i386 armv7 armv7s x86_64 arm64`

and **security.framework** is linked

Thank you in advance
Greetings
D

Comment: were you able to proceed any further ?

Answer (score 3):

The following functions are possibly missing from the "libcurl.a" file. Did you compile libcurl yourself? If so, look for some compilation options that will possibly enable the inclusion of those functions, and recompile.

```
SSLDisposeContext()
SSLNewContext()
SSLSetEnableCertVerify()
SSLSetProtocolVersionEnabled()
SecCertificateCopyLongDescription()
```

Also, this existing question on Stack Overflow might help: [libcurl linker error on Xcode5 but working fine on Xcode 4.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294737/libcurl-linker-error-on-xcode5-but-working-fine-on-xcode-4-6) (essentially, your libcurl version might be too old, so check for an update)

EDIT: The problem might be related to the Security Framework, as Mobile Ben mentioned in the comments. Still, the linked question might help.

Comment: SSLDisposeContext et al are part of the Security Framework (Defined in SecurityTransport.h), not part of curl. I had actually included the flag you were talking about (--with-darwinssl) after reading your answer, but then re-read the question. It is the functions like SSLDisposeContext that are missing.

Comment: And reading your link you included that seems right. Sorry missed that last part!

Comment: It actually is lib curl 7.39.0 i've used this ruby stuff to create the lib: https://github.com/brunodecarvalho/curl-ios-build-scripts. I altered it a little to build a complete fatlib (all archs). If I build it for the device (not the simulator) then no linker errors occuring (I've noticed today)

Answer (score 0):

Did you forgot to add the -ObjC linker flag ??

The linker tries to be efficient about only including needed code, which can sometimes exclude static library code. With this flag, all the Objective-C classes and categories in the library are loaded properly.

[image]

[image]